# Search end exclude in xml with java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm trying to search these occurrences in xml file:

```
<xml>  
<corpus>  
<body>  
<nonterminals>  
<graph>  
<s>  
<nt id="s9_509" cat="fcl"></nt>  

<nt id="s9_501" cat="pp">  
                <edge label="H" idref="s9_1"/>  
                <edge label="DP" idref="s9_502"/>  
                <edge label="STA" idref="s9_509"/>  
                <edge label="P" idref="s9_19"/>  
                <edge label="S" idref="s9_510"/>  
                <edge label="PU" idref="s9_25"/>  
            </nt>  
</nonterminals>  
</graph>  
</s>  
</body>  
</corpus>  
</xml>
```

And my code is:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();    
String path = "//xml//corpus//build//s//graph//nonterminals//nt";  
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(path);    
System.out.println("Query1: "+path);  
Object result = expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);    
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;    
System.out.println("Number of nodes: "+nodes.getLength());  
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {    
    System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue());
```

This query its correct?
Exists another way to try it?
How do I delete the Node findings?

Comment: I think using `//` in `xml//corpus` will also consider any intermediate tags in between the two tags. You should have `//` only at the starting, and then afterwards you should just use `/`.

Comment: I already tried that, but the number of nodes findings still 0

Comment: I'm guessing this is a typo, but your XML has invalid nesting <nonterminals><graph><s>...</nonterminals></graph></s>

Comment: This is a valid XML, but I'm guessing this is not the problem, I will review the code for errors, thanks

Comment: I can assure you that your example above is *NOT* valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

Providing that this is the entire structure of your XML and `<xml>` is your root node, I would say that your XPath should be:

```
/xml/corpus/build/s/graph/nonterminals/nt
```

If you want to match **every** `nt` node regardless of where it appears in the document, you could use:

```
//nt
```

There are useful free tools for seeing the results of XPath queries without needing to write java upfront:

http://xml-copy-editor.sourceforge.net/

http://www.xpathtester.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll enter the link after